# Power series and its equivalent series

Tags: analysis, power-series, proof-explanation

I am currently faced with this equation. However, I am stuck witth the last equality. May I know how did the $x^4$ disappear and then the factorial changed from $(2n)!$ to $(2n+2)!$ ? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: The writer made a substitution, replacing $n-1$ with $n$.  It is a bit confusing because "$n$" is used twice.  Perhaps you would find it clearer if you introduced a new dummy variable as $m=n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is the equaliy$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{4(n-1)}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{4n}}{(2n+2)!}.$$What does the LHS *mean*? It means:$$-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^8}{6!}+\cdots\tag{1}$$And what does the RHS *mean*? Well, it means $(1)$, too.